# Shouldn't non-English SE sites be excluded from Hot Network Questions?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

Hot Network Questions (HNQ) are an eyecatcher of very strong leverage. To be placed there attracts a lot of attention. And posts are (AFAIK) tested for strict requirements to get there. To keep HNQ's content and purpose as interesting as possible.

But why then there are non-English sites sometimes displayed, where just a fraction of the community is even able to understand?

This question comes up to after I now have seen there a post on Spanish Stack Overflow for multiple times and I'm not even able to say it were different posts or the title just has been changed since I can't translate what its about.

So my question: Is this really what the HNQs should support?

Comment: Wait. They *are* excluded. Except, probably, the brand-new es.SO (is that what you mean to reference?), though I haven't seen it in HNQ either.

Comment: ahhhh ok so just nobody added it to the exclude list so far? Then I'm fine.

Comment: "them " = what? Also, the sites about languages are not excluded, but those sites are about learning languages.

Comment: uhm them means the spanish people... But exchange it to "it" since I was meaning the spanish SO site by "them" :x

Comment: @Robert Cartaino: Is this a duplicate? It seems this one is about Spanish.SE, French.SE etc. whereas the other is about the localized SOs. Though it may also be that the questions were simply worded in a sloppy way. – BTW, there is a question from Italian.SE in the HNQ sidebar right next to this comment at the time of writing. :-)