# es.SO questions aren't excluded from the Hot Questions list

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions, sidebar

As figured out in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271193/232136) localized SE sites must not be displayed in the HNQ's. But [es.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271193/232136) actually is.

> [image]

Has to be fixed I guess?

Comment: Sounds like someone forgot to update a list somewhere, as es.SO is new. (there's probably no "show in HNQ sidebar" column, just a static list of sites to exclude)

Comment: Any updates on why they still are part of HNQ sidebar?

Comment: Don't ask me (I'm the only one who got notified of your comment), I'm just ordinary user like you.

Comment: I didn't address this to anyone. I was hoping a comment may be something that helps getting generell attention but seems I was wrong

Comment: Comments draw no attention, I'm afraid. You can edit the question, or start a bounty, those are the common ways to bump - but I've seen bugs that exist for years without getting any fix or even hint of attention, so don't expect for too much.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that they *should* be excluded. That linked post doesn't state that this should be the case. Surely one of the purposes of the HQ list is to make people aware of sites they may not otherwise know about. I don't see why foreign-language ones are an exception. I find it equally as relevant to my interests as mathematics.se or code golf (i.e. no interest). But some people may find it useful to know these sites exist.

Comment: @JonW: yeah thats right. But then anyway: Why is it one and only that es.SO and nothing else? And now imagine for equality reasons the other foreign language pages get there aswell: I wouldn't even paying attention that much anymore if there were 20-30% of the HNQ's of sites where I can't even understand the language. And thats probably not what the HNQ are designed for, is it?

Comment: I agree it should be all or nothing, but if a site is receiving enough attention to trigger the HNQ criteria then I would say that whether the majority of people understand the language is no more/less relevant than if the majority of people understand the subject-matter. I just don't want us working from an assumption that they shouldn't be displayed when in fact that assumption is wrong in the first place.

Comment: @JonW: Ok, so we have the same point. But actually this isn't that relevant because then the question is one of: 1) Why only es.SO is in HNQ? or: Why is es.SO in HNQ? What ever of this it is, there is something wrong. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard probably most reliable way to really draw attention would be to create login at es.SO and lemming-upvote everything in their questions that pop up in the HNQ

Comment: @gnat not sure how that would draw attention? That is what already happening for most HNQ questions.

Comment: @ShadowWizard currently there are two es.SO questions in the list, that looks tolerable. Think of what would happen when there will be 7-8 of them over there

Comment: @gnat oh, I thought you mean upvoting the questions already in the list. Well, I think the limit is 3 per site, so still - no extra attention. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard per my recollection, there's no such limit. I recall seeing up to 5-6 questions from SO, Workplace, Math. Hey, I just found a [documented case](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/how-come-there-are-5-workplace-questions-in-the-hot-list#comment4211_2457) of seven TWP questions in the list

Comment: @gnat talking only about the sidebar of each site, not the global list. Only few people visit the full list, most just see the sidebar. (as far as I can tell)

Comment: @ShadowWizard understood, thanks. Now, if the full list gets 7-8 questions from one site, think of the chances for sidebar to be occupied by 2-3 of them

Comment: @gnat huh, now that's a valid point. Good luck upvoting all the possible HNQ! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard [feel the irony](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgb9t.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I flipped the relevant site setting on, so SOes questions should be dropped the next time the sidebar list refreshes.

Comment: Hey. Can we do the same for Portugese? I just spotted https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4598/esse-humilhou-se-a-si-mesmo-da-b%C3%ADblia-%C3%A9-redundante-ou-tem-alguma-explica%C3%A7%C3%A3o on the HNQ bar. Thanks :) ...I asked here, because other, similar questions (eg https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271343/266359 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271139/266359) were closed as duplicates of this question.

Comment: Can we do this for SOru questions as well (it appears [it was done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252518/questions-from-ru-so-shouldnt-become-hot), however they are showing again), I just had https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949940/local-storage-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null appear in my list :) (I came here for the same reason as Shokhet)

Comment: @NickA We recently had to change how we check for non-English questions. Long story short, we switched to a language detector library and checking the title alone, not the body. Might need to revisit that (or hard-exclude international sites entirely), evidently... but for the moment, this is what we've got.

Comment: @AdamLear Any chance of more information or an update to the title filter?, [Meryの青い線の外し方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/53422/mery%E3%81%AE%E9%9D%92%E3%81%84%E7%B7%9A%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%96%E3%81%97%E6%96%B9) just appeared in HNQ :)

Comment: @NickA I ended up excluding international SO sites from HNQ earlier today, so those shouldn't be showing up anymore.