# Please do not include questions not in English in "Hot Network Questions"

Tags: feature-request, bug, hot-questions, languages

Today, I got some Spanish "Hot Network Questions", having read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256614/include-non-english-websites-in-hot-network-questions-based-on-users-location) it looks like a filter was supposed to be in place. I'm sure it's interesting but to my shame I do not know Spanish.

That question contains no English, it does contain some shell commands that are in English but certainly not text.

Please fine tune the filter or make these questions opt-in.