# Which sites are excluded or limited from Hot Network Questions?

Tags: support, hot-questions, faq-proposed

I was curious but couldn't find any definitive listing on this. Is there an official list of sites excluded from Hot Network Questions somewhere?

Additionally, which sites are penalized from Hot Network Questions, to prevent the list from being dominated by that site?

Comment: Related: [Revisiting the "Hot Network Questions" feature, what are our shared goals for having it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

### Excluded

- [SE sites with non-English interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271193) ([localized Stack Overflow sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252518) and [Russian language in Russian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257066))
- [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280505)
- Per-site metas, including Area 51 Discussions
- Stack Apps
- Private beta sites

  - [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com) is internally considered a private beta site, even though it's accessible to the public

### Limited (by hotness score)

These sites can still contribute the same number of questions to Hot Network Questions, but their questions need higher hotness score to be selected.

**Heavily (80% penalty factor)**

- [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226304)

**Quite (45% penalty factor)**

- Software Engineering
- [The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2457)

References: [How is hotness score calculated at larger sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246925), [penalty factor per-site (higher value = smaller hotness score)](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7327766#7327766)

### Limited (by number of questions)

Questions on these sites can still end up in Hot Network Questions with the same hotness score, but these sites contribute fewer than the default five questions at a time.

**1 question at a time**

- [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3642/lets-go-back-to-hnq)

---

### Past occurrences

- [Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5713) (quite limited by hotness score; effectively excluded)
- [Sexuality](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7327216#7327216) (excluded)
- [Interpersonal Skills](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316976/278659) (excluded)

Comment: @Somewhat there is a blacklist of terms that keeps the most problematic questions from sites like Skeptics out of the HNQ.

Comment: @MadScientist where? Is it public?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The list is not public as far as I know, a few terms are known and there are some scattered meta posts about it, but not easy to find. This is one meta post that shows the existence of the list: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242047/151385

Comment: @gnat I also couldn't find it on their respective meta, but I'd take [Jon's meta post on Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5713) and [Shog direct statement on chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7327188#7327188) as the source of truth. I've also asked Shog to review this answer, but there's no comment on both sites.

Comment: see [my fact-check at the Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7327664#7327664): "I see 6 (six) Workplace questions in HNQ right now: #121410, #121411, #121512, #121499, #121395, #121407". I can't tell where Shog has got his idea but it certainly is not true

Comment: speaking of Software Eng it it harder to make such an overwhelming proof but if necessary I can invest some time and demonstrate that it isn't penalized either, it pops in HNQ frequently enough to gather representative set of examples. Maybe this can even be proven based on [Glorfindel's database](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315017/165773) of hot questions

Comment: If I interpret Jon's chat message correctly, Workplace and Software Engineering are penalized *more* than Stack Overflow, not *less* (apart from the traffic factor).

Comment: @Glorfindel I interpret the value to be "reduced by", based on [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246925/241919) where he stated `*0.2` (assuming SO: 1-**0.8**)

Answer (score 120):

I'm posting this as an answer as this change worries me a great deal.

Not the fact that it happened, but **how** it happened.

Someone tweeted a complaint on Twitter about HNQ and didn't explicitly ask for anything to happen.  This happened at 11:39pm (UTC).

40 minutes later, an SE developer tweeted back stating "Yes I agree, I've pushed a change to remove that site from the HNQ".

[Twitter exchange](https://twitter.com/aalear/status/1052322898252304384)

So, there's been a change to the site's behaviour in 40 minutes based on an external tweet.

If someone in my team pushed out a live change in that kind of time, they'd be hauled up in front of management and asked why the hell they were bypassing the change process.

Was this change discussed? Were the moderators of IPS informed up front? Or is this (as it seems to be), a rogue developer pushing changes out?

Comment: We have so far recieved no input about this. I know the moderators were informed after the fact (I don't know the timeline), and I know IPS meta hasn't had a post about it. I propose we hold judgement for now until staff had an opportunity to explain their reasoning.

Comment: I won't call it "rogue developer", more like panic action, fearing the outcome if it won't be changed in that instant.

Comment: I agree.  My main concern here is that a change went live seemingly within 40 minutes of the initial report.  That implies that there wasn't much in the way of discussion/approval/testing before this was released. In my world, that's a bad thing.  and I saw nothing in the twitter exchange that seemed to merit an immediate call to action.

Comment: And to put it into perspective, the HNQ and better ways to maintain it have been discussed *extensively for years* on [meta.se], with the general takeaway from SE that there's allegedly no problem to fix and nothing to be changed in that regard.

Comment: I don't understand why this twitter user is even being paid attention to? Looking at the replies in the thread it's very obvious that they have no intention of actually being constructive, they just want to moan.

Comment: @Pyritie Yep, that tweet is definitely a case of [someone is wrong on the internet](https://xkcd.com/386/). Maybe not *moan*, but *score a point* without doing any serious investigation. Well, that's Twitter.

Comment: You may want to add context that this is about Interpersonal Relationships being removed from HNQ. I was initially confused, as I hadn't about what happened.

Comment: @Pyritie it seems why they cared is because one of stackexchange's behind-the-scenes stakeholders saw the tweet and was worried: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317011/what-are-the-effective-communication-channels-for-effecting-change-to-se?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1040150_317221

Comment: That tweet has since been deleted. Has it been preserved somewhere, perhaps as a screen shot? I'm curious to learn what the offending questions were.

Comment: @SQB There's a screenshot in [this other meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316976/229671).

Comment: @JohnGowers thank you. I remember having seen it since asking. Please flag this one for deletion as "no longer needed" after reading.