# Are questions posted to the "Meta" of a Stack Exchange site eligible for Hot Network Questions?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, hot-questions

Well, I have been on the Stack Exchange network for a while and you know, your eyes often go to the Hot Network Questions page or pane, maybe both.

I never saw a question posted to a Meta of the sites, there so, I was wondering if they are eligible for Hot Network Questions or not?

Comment: [Which sites are excluded or limited from Hot Network Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316904/which-sites-are-excluded-or-limited-from-hot-network-questions) says that questions on all meta sites are excluded.

Comment: Questions on per-site metas, Meta Stack Exchange, Stack Apps, and non-English sites [are excluded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316906/312043)